# upgraded to rails 3, and now autospec in my rails 2 projects just exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've been working on a rails 2.3.8 app for a long time now. Autospec has been working like a champ. Last night, I started a new app in rails 3 and after some shenanigans got autospec working for rails 3.

Now, in my rails 2 apps, when I run autospec, I get a single line of output and then it exits.

```
loading autotest/rails_rspec
```

I've backed out of everything I did to get rails 3 working last night but still no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run it through bundle

```
bundle exec autotest
```